# Image Slider with captions in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses on Internet: PHP, JavaScript, mySQL, CSS and HTML.

Now I decided to continue learning from the practice, so I started building a Wordpress theme.

I am making an image slider. I know that I can simply download a Wordpress plugin, but as all people say that is better to use jQuery plugins ( to have a faster site) I downloaded a jQuery plugin.

I started downloading a plugin called [bxslider](http://bxslider.com) but like all the jQuery plugins that I have found since a week of research, it doesn't let me take out the image caption to a different div. So is obligatory to has the image caption at the bottom of the image or inside the image.

As I said before I am making my first steps coding so I don't know if it's better to learn how to make an slider by my self than looking for a jQuery plugin.

Do you have some suggestion? Something that I could use as a guide to start building a basic image slider with captions in Wordpress? I see that there's no jQuery plugin that can provides me a solution to separate the caption from the image, so if it's doesn't exist I thing that I should create one by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily develop something yourself without a plugin. It depends what style you want; do you want a slider on timer or one that slides on click? I have included examples of both

Slider with timer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //INDEX IMAGES SLIDER
  $(function slider() {

    //configuration
    var width = 360;
    var speed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var current = 1;


    //cache DOM
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('#slides');
    var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');


    setInterval(function() {
      //move image the defined width and speed to the left
      $slides.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width
      }, speed, function() {
        //count number of slides and loop back to first from last
        current++;
        if (current === $slide.length) {
          current = 1;

          $slides.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
      });
    }, pause);
  });
});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 360px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider #slides {
  display: block;
  width: 1440px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 250px;
  width: 360px;
}

#slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">

  <ul id="slides">

    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/bara3.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.musicmatters.ie/images/volunteer2.jpg"></li>

  </ul>


</div>
```

Click on slide (with captions)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rotator > a.arrow.left').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var rotator = $('#rotator .images');
    rotator.children('.imageHolder').first().animate({
      marginLeft: "-=310px"
    }, function() {
      $(this).appendTo(rotator).removeAttr("style");
    });
  });
  $('#rotator > a.arrow.right').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var rotator = $('#rotator .images');
    rotator.children('.imageHolder').last().prependTo(rotator).removeAttr("style").css("margin-left", "-310px").animate({
      marginLeft: "0"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#rotator {
  width: 310px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#rotator .images {
  width: 1000%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#rotator a.arrow {
  width: 18px;
  height: 41px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  text-indent: -50000em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 89px;
}

#rotator a.arrow.left {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/leftarrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#rotator a.arrow.right {
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/rightarrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#rotator .images .imageHolder {
  width: 310px;
  float: left;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

#rotator .images .imageHolder span {
  width: 290px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

#rotator .images .imageHolder img {
  width: 310px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotator">
        <a href="#" class="arrow left"></a>
        <div class="images">
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <span>Daisies</span>
                <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daisies.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <span>Snowdrops</span>
                <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <span>Mountains</span>
                <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <span>Yellow Flowers</span>
                <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/yellowflowers.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="arrow right"></a>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: 1. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/fs9u6mwe/  2. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/d8as3p4k/

Comment: Thank you very much Rachel, but I still continue with the same problem: I can't take out the captions from the slider. take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/d8as3p4k/3/

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain correctly. I mean take the Title and place it in other place out from the slider. For example in the footer of the page

Comment: did you try the 3rd option http://www.jsfiddle.net/3gnhxhny9/2  i think it's better for you

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't saw it. It works perfectly! Thank you very much!